# angularjs state change animation slide in and out

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

In a single page application, I want to give slide-right for new pages and slide-left for old pages when clicking on the button. Before my state change, I tried to apply the corresponding css class (thanks to http://dfsq.github.io/ngView-animation-effects/app/#/page/1) to the element having ui-view directive.

In the html if I keep the class, the animation works correctly. But always in one direction.

```
<div class="site-wrapper slide-right" ui-view></div>
```

But since I have to switch between slide-right and slide-left, I apply the class to ui-view element dynamically as given below.

```
<div class="site-wrapper" ui-view></div>

 if(args.slideDir && args.slideDir==='slide-right') {                    
    angular.element(document.querySelector(elt)).removeClass('slide-left');
    angular.element(document.querySelector(elt)).addClass('slide-right');
 } else {
    angular.element(document.querySelector(elt)).removeClass('slide-right');
    angular.element(document.querySelector(elt)).addClass('slide-left');
 }

 $state.go(args.hash);
```

But the page animation works like this. 
[image]

And the real culprit is, AngularJS uses my old DOM while cloning the ui-view element.

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Yes it's totally doable. This video is helpful to understand how `<ui-view>` gets cloned to allow for animations https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W89DYSthCTQ

Comment: @charlietfl I could not find a way to handle my scenario in the video. Even I am using ng-enter and ng-leave. But as I mentioned I cannot associate the CSS class statically in the html. I have to switch between slideIn and slideOut in the same container.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. ng-class is the key. Use ng-class instead of class.

```
<div class="site-wrapper" ng-class="slideDir" ui-view></div>

$state.go(args.hash, {slideDir:'slide-right'});//for slide right

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
    if(toParams.slideDir && toParams.slideDir==='slide-right') {        
        $rootScope.slideDir = "slide-right";
    } else { //back button will not have any params associated
        $rootScope.slideDir = "slide-left";
    }               
});
```